# Adding space in Xamarin.Forms layouts?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

What's the proposed way to add **space to layouts** in [Xamarin.Forms](http://xamarin.com/forms)?

One way would be to add a **Frame with no children** like so:

```
new Frame {
    BackgroundColor = Color.White,
    HeightRequest = 1,
    MinimumHeightRequest = 1,
    HasShadow = false
}
```

Unfortunately, `HeightRequest` and `MinimumHeightRequest` get ignored.

Does a better way exist?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could put your controls inside layouts (like frame, scroll view, stack panel) and use Padding property:

```cs
        this.stackPanel = new StackLayout () 
        {
            Padding = new Thickness (8, 8)
        };  

        var scrollView = new ScrollView () 
        {
            Content = stackPanel,
            Padding = new Thickness (1, 2, 3, 4)
        };

        var frame = new Frame () 
        {
            Padding = new Thickness (8)
        };
```

If you want space between two buttons for example, I believe this would do the trick. The first one adds 10 to bottom padding, the second adds 10 to top padding for total of 20.

```cs
        var frame1 = new Frame () 
        {
            Padding = new Thickness (0,0,0,10),
            Content = new Button()
        };

        var frame2 = new Frame () 
        {
            Padding = new Thickness (0,10,0,0),
            Content = new Button()
        };
```

Comment: FYI this does not work within a collectionview template. It will expand the items fill space rather then the space between items

Answer (score 9):

Most `Xamarin.Forms` Layouts supports adding space between elements:

- `StackLayout` has a `Spacing` property,
- `Grid` has `RowSpacing` and `ColumnSpacing` properties,
- ...

Now, if you want to add spacing at a particular place, the way to to it is to include a `BoxView`:

```cs
myStackLayout.Children.Add (new BoxView {Color = Color.Transparent, HeightRequest = 5});
```

You can also wrap your content in a `Frame` or `ContentView`, but it adds padding to the content instead of adding space (although the effect will be the same).

Answer (score 5):

What I do worked perfectly for me:

Suppose you want to distribute 2 Labels evenly on a horizontal StackLayout:

```
new StackLayout
{
    Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
    HorizontalOptions=LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
    Spacing = 0, // <- Very important!!
    Children = {
        new Label { Text = "Label 1" },
        new BoxView { HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand }, // <- the clever part
        new Label { Text = "Label 2" }
    }
};
```

**Summary**

By inserting BoxViews that fill the remaining space ("FillAndExpand") between your views, your views appear evenly distributed.
By setting `Spacing = 0`, you don't get extra space between your views.

Comment: This is the exact hacky technique I use.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
myFrame.TranslateX=10;
myFrame.TranslateY=10;
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to share a screenshot in conjunction with Lay González's answer but the edit queue was full->

To get dynamic spacing similar to CSS "Space-Between" in Xamarin you can insert filler views between your views that actually have content.

Here is an example:

[image]

Omit the filler view after the last "actual" view so that the view you want is at the end (the "-50" label at the bottom in the example).